# 2 value , 3 spaces - how to loop through to return all different variations

Tags: python

If I have 2 values:

1. X and Y

And 3 spaces - `["","",""]`

How to create a looping mechanism to return all different variations?

E.g.

```
Variation 1 = [X,X,X]
Variation 2 = [X,X,Y]
.....
Variation .. = [Y,Y,Y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is itertools.product(). It allows you to create what you want in a simple one-liner:

```
import itertools

a=[]
X=1
Y=2
a.append(X)
a.append(Y)

combinations = list(itertools.product(a,repeat=3))

print(combinations)
```

Output

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```